# Integration of FullCalendar into Apache Royale

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4, apache-royale

I'd like to start a Apache Royale Project which needs Calendar/Scheduler functionality. I have been working a lot with [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io) which is a great library. Would it be possible to integrate FullCalendar in Royale and if so, how should I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd started working on a basic way of doing this - wrapping up the JavaScript functionality that I found from FullCalendar 4.1.0 and using the 'default' sample as a model. Putting this into a simple AS3 class means that you can then use the functionality from within your MXML files or create it within AS3, and manipulate it as you would any other Royale UI element.

More work needs doing to this - i.e. supporting the other plug-in types (fairly straightforward to do) and extending the API that's supported. But it shows how it can be done.. feel free to suggest/contribute changes! I've put it into github [here](https://github.com/ajwfrost/royale-playground/tree/master/CalendarProject)

Thanks

Comment: I tried to use your library. It gives this compilation error: D:\Project\FolderStructure\io\fullcalendar\FullCalendar.as(153): col: 25 Error: Definition Calendar could not be found.
    [mxmlc]
    [mxmlc]             _calendar = new window["FullCalendar"].Calendar(positioner, options);

Any idea?

Comment: If that's at compile-time, then it implies it can't find the definitions for that third party calendar library. I don't actually recall how we did this, but the simple option may be to turn off "strict" mode in the as3 compiler? or you may be able to pick up a reference to the FullCalendar library using "-compiler.js-external-library-path"? Although I didn't appear to have either of those settings, judging by the Moonshine project file. Potentially something has changed in the compiler/set-up in the past 4 years..

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Will try to find some other example to integrate JS into Royale.